# Find the minimum value of $\sqrt{x^2+8x+85}+\sqrt{x^2-8x+113}$

Tags: analysis, functions

How can I find the minimum value of $\sqrt{x^2+8x+85}+\sqrt{x^2-8x+113}$.
I've tried derivating it but didn't reach any result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

You need first to find where the minimum occurs and your function is of the type $$F(x)=\sqrt {A(x)}+\sqrt {B(x)}$$ So, $$F'(x)=\frac{A'(x)}{2 \sqrt{A(x)}}+\frac{B'(x)}{2 \sqrt{B(x)}}$$ and you want this expression to be zero. Then write $$\frac{A'(x)}{B'(x)}=-\sqrt {\frac{A(x)}{B(x)}}$$ and square both sides. You should arrive to something manageable.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Got it. Thanks !

Comment: You are very welcome ! Glad to help. Cheers :)